# How to use ${PRODUCT_NAME} in different plist?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a way to access the value of ${PRODUCT_NAME} (or any other user defined build setting) that is defined in the project settings from a different plist?

Answer (score 0):

well technically speaking an XML file by itself does not read other files %)

but maybe this solves the question about how to read the info.plis file from code:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:key_name];
```